# Duda en los conceptos de Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menú

Buenas a todos,

Estoy migrando un sitio web estático a WP (una plantilla). En el sitio web que he creado en html y css ya dispongo de un menú de navegación, pero tengo una duda ¿al migrar a Wordpress es necesario crear un menú de navegación desde el backoffice?

Por lo que me he estado documentando los pasos correctos serian: Crear una plantilla nueva, crear los archivos basicos (functions.php, style.css y index.php), crear el resto de archivos (single.php, search.php etc) y crear el loop. ¿Es correcto o me falta algún paso?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario que lo crees, pero si quieres que el sitio sea dinámico lo suyo seria crearlo.

Al final estas pasando de una página estática a una dinámica como bien has dicho, y nunca sera una página totalmente dinámica si no tiene un menú que pueda ser gestionado desde algún sistema de administración.

En cualquiera de los casos lo que te recomendaria es que aprovechases la migracion a Wordpress para cambiar el diseño de la web, ya que existen multiples plantillas que te pueden ayudar.

Del mismo modo, así aprendes todas las partes de las que se compone una plantilla de Wordpress y puede ayudarte a crear tu propio tema mas adelante.

Puedes modificar una `plantilla hijo` todo lo que quieras sin problemas:

https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Temas_hijos

De esa manera, veras como se crean los menús en Wordpress y podrás ir poco a poco aprendiendo la estructura y demás.

Comment: Lo único que no me queda claro, si tengo el menú creado y lo creo desde WP, ¿el menú que he creado en HTML lo tengo que eliminar?

Comment: Yo haría todos los menús dinámicos, es la gracia de tener un CMS como Wordpress, que no necesites tocar "código" para poder hacer modificaciones. Cuanto menos cosas tengas "a fuego" mejor.